# using datagridview for 2 different queries, 1 at a time clearing previous datasource in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable, dataset

**I have multiple queries need to be shown on single Datagridview. Query runs one at a time. The problem is when while running the second query the previous query data columns will still exist and concatenate to new query.**

Example Query1: A,B,C,D columns are shown on datagridview
Query2: has E,F,G columns but when I run the Query 2 it shows A,B,C,D,E,F,G.

I need only E,F,G to be displayed. wasnt able to clear the columns

### Query1:

```
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT vouchertype as [Voucher Type], voucherdate as [Voucher Date],VoucherNo as [Voucher No.], Party as [party Name], DISCOUNT,TAX,NETAMOUNT  FROM SALESREPORT where vouchertype='Sale' and VOUCHERDATE BETWEEN '" & DATE1.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "' "
        End With
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
```

### Query2:

```
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT DESCRIPTION AS [ITEM PARTICULAR], [TYPE] AS [TRANSACTION], REF AS [REFERENCE], QTY AS [QUANTITY], OPENINGBALANCE, OPENINGVALUE, INWARDSQTY,INWARDSVALUE, OUTWARDSQTY,OUTWARDSVALUE FROM STOCK_MOVEMENT WHERE DATES BETWEEN '" & DATE1.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "' "
        End With
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
```

Things I Tried:

```
Try
        dt.Columns.Clear()
        dt.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        dt.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        dTable.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        ds.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: put `cmd.dispose()` after each queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `DataTable` each time rather than reusing an existing one.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```